# What is the Python equivalent for the R function names( )?

Tags: python

The function `names()` in R gets or sets the names of an object. What is the Python equivalent to this function, including import?

**Usage:**

```
names(x)

names(x) <- value
```

**Arguments:**

(x) an R object.

(value) a character vector of up to the same length as x, or NULL.

**Details:**

`Names()` is a generic accessor function, and names<- is a generic replacement function. The default methods get and set the "names" attribute of a vector (including a list) or pairlist.

[Continue R Documentation on Names( )](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python (pandas) we have `.columns` function which is equivalent to `names()` function in R:

Ex:

```
# Import pandas package  
import pandas as pd  

# making data frame  
data = pd.read_csv("Filename.csv")  

# Extract column names
list(data.columns)
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure if there is anything directly equivalent, especially for getting names.  some objects, like `dict`s, provide `.keys()` method that allows getting things out

sort of relevant are the `getattr` and `setattr` primitives, but it's pretty rare to use these in production code

I was going to talk about Pandas, but I see user2357112 has just pointed that out already!

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent. The concept does not exist in Python. Some specific types have roughly analogous concepts, like the index of a Pandas Series, but arbitrary Python sequence types don't have names for their elements.